# Multiprocessing using Python: How to parallelize nested loops and append results to dictionary?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, multiprocess

I am new to multiprocessing in Python and currently I am not sure how to proceed with the problem in my hand. I am trying to implement a function which has two loops (inner and outer loop) and append the results in a dictionary. The function and what I would like to achieve looks something like:

```
def func(p, a):
    return p*a

p_dict = dict()
for p in all_possible_ps:    #I would like to parallelize this
    alist = list()

    for a in all_possible_as:    #And this for loop
        alist.append(func(p,a))

    p_dict[p] = alist
```

For the inner loop, I believe I can instantiate a pool, `p=Pool()`, then `p.map(func, all_possible_as)` to get `alist`. I am not sure how to parallelize both loops and at the same time distribute the number of processes for both loops.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two different pools, and then nest them.  Here I'm using `pathos` (it includes a fork of `multiprocessing` with the necessary serialization to pass a lambda across a pool).

If you look at a for loop, with a function of two variables, you can think of this kind of progression...

```
>>> doit = lambda x,y: x*y
>>> a = [0,1,2,3]
>>> b = [9,8,7,6]
>>> [[doit(i,j) for j in b] for i in a]
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [9, 8, 7, 6], [18, 16, 14, 12], [27, 24, 21, 18]]
```

to nested parallel:

```
>>> from pathos.pools import ThreadPool, ProcessPool
>>> p = ProcessPool()
>>> t = ThreadPool()
>>> foo = lambda x,y: p.map(doit, [x]*len(y), y) 
>>> t.map(foo, a, [b]*4)
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [9, 8, 7, 6], [18, 16, 14, 12], [27, 24, 21, 18]]
```

`imap` is just a map iterator.  You can use `map` if you prefer, but I'll use `imap` below. I believe the function you are looking for specifically is something like this:

```
>>> bar = lambda x,y: (x, p.map(doit, [x]*len(y), y)) 
>>> res = t.imap(bar, a, [b]*4)
>>> adict = {}
>>> for i,j in res:
...   adict[i] = j
... 
>>> adict
{0: [0, 0, 0, 0], 1: [9, 8, 7, 6], 2: [18, 16, 14, 12], 3: [27, 24, 21, 18]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way.  You can  use `multiprocessing.Pool` instead if you're on Python 2.7.

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

p_dict = {}

# submit jobs
with ProcessPoolExecutor() as pool:
    for p in all_possible_ps:
        p_dict[p] = [pool.submit(func, p, a) for a in all_possible_as]

# collect results
for p, alist in p_dict.items():
    for ii, fut in enumerate(alist):
        alist[ii] = fut.result()
```